# Upload files to specific folder

Tags: python, django

Structure of my project

```
untitled2
      --mysite
      --media
           --audio
           --css
           --img
           --js
      untitled2
        --media
        --templates
        --settings.py
        --urls.py
```

## models.py

```
class Audio(models.Model):
    link_mp     = models.FileField(upload_to='audio/')
```

## settings.py

```
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'media/')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

> When i upload file from admin my file copy to the
>   untitled2-->untitled2-->media, but i want copy it to
>   utitled2-->media-->audio

Answer (score 1):

Your `SITE_ROOT` is the `/untitled2/untitled2/` subfolder where your `settings.py` is, so your `media` root is therefore `/untitled2/untitled2/media/` and your `upload_to` is `/untitled2/untitled2/media/audio/`. Change your media root to use `/untitled/media` instead

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(SITE_ROOT), 'media/')
```